# Grails params not coming through

Tags: grails

I have a grails controller:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.transaction.Transactional

class ProfileController {
  static allowedMethods = [index: "GET", update: "PUT"]

  def index() {
    println "inside index"
    //...
  }

  @Transactional
  def update(Profile profile) {
    println "inside update"
    println "thing ${profile}"
    println "params ${params}"
    //...
  }
}
```

with the following URL mappings:

```
    '/profile'(controller: 'profile', action: 'index', method: 'GET')
    '/profile'(controller: 'profile', action: 'update', method: 'PUT')
```

Unfortunately, nothing is coming through in the `PUT` action for profile or params.

I'm hitting it via:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/profile' -X PUT --data-binary '{"phoneNumber":"020-30303030"}'
```

Running that I see:

```
 inside update
 thing null
 params [controller:profile, action:update]
```

Any idea why params and/or profile data binding are not being populated with the data?

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: Grails 3.0.8 @JoshuaMoore

Comment: `profile` will be null unless a valid `id` for Profile representing the json body is passed in the payload. `params` will not have the payload for POST/PUT but `request` will, in the form of `request.JSON`. Pass the id in the json body with `phoneNumber` to make the data binding work. Domain based data binding will not be able to figure out which Profile is being referred in the PUT request until the identifier is passed. Makes sense?

Comment: Fantastic @dmahapatro.  Thanks for your help.  If you want the reputation make an answer and ill happily accept it